# R: ksvm with parameter C

Tags: r, svm

I want to tune the parameter C in ksvm. Now I'm wondering how this C is defined.
The definition of C is

> cost of constraints violation (default: 1) this is the `C'-constant of
>   the regularization term in the Lagrange formulation.

Does this mean that the larger C is, the more misclassifications are allowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cost parameter penalizes large residuals.  So a larger cost will result in a more flexible model with fewer misclassifications.  In effect the cost parameter allows you to adjust the bias/variance trade-off.  The greater the cost parameter, the more variance in the model and the less bias.

So the answer to your question is no.  The greater the cost, the fewer misclassifications are allowed.

This is explained in Chapter 7 Section 3 of the book [Applied Predictive Modeling](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1461468485) by Kuhn.

Note how this is the opposite of regularization which penalizes large coefficients, resulting in higher bias and lower variance.  Here we penalize the residuals resulting in higher variance and lower bias.